# Find the Taylor series generated by f at x=a.

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

> $f(x) = \frac 1 {9 - x}, a = 3$.

The answer in the book is $$\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{(x - 3)^n}{6^{n + 1}}$$but I'm not sure how to get the above.

Comment: I've edited your post to format the math in it; please check that it says what you intended.

Answer (score 1):

We know that:

$$\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots$$

I assume that $a$ is the center that you want to write the Taylor expansion around it.

Therefore:

$$\frac{1}{9-x}=\frac{1}{6}\frac{1}{1-\frac{(x-3)}{6}}=\frac{1}{6} \cdot (1+\frac{(x-3)}{6}+\cdots+\frac{(x-3)^n}{6^n})$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**
You can write
$$
\frac{1}{9-x}
= \frac{1}{6 - (x - 3)}
= \frac16 \frac{1}{1 - \left( \frac{x-3}{6} \right)}
$$
Then use the fact that
$$
\frac{1}{1 - y} = \sum_{k \ge 0} y^k.
$$